# ARM ассемблер - вызов функции

Tags: ассемблер, arm

В одном ассемблерном листинге под ядро ARM926EJ-S обнаружил несколько странных для меня вызовов. Весь код отображается по большим адресам: 0x44000000, например. Оперативная память и периферия тоже вся высоко сидит.

Но в коде неоднократно встречаются такие команды:

```
LDR     R3, =0xE4D
BX      R3
```

То есть переход по адресу очень маленькому. Вряд ли это какая-то ошибка или самодурство компилятора.
Что же сие может означать? Даташита нема, а опыт общения с армами у меня ещё не настолько велик.

Comment: Моя версия: основной код сидит во внешней большой памяти, кой и транслируется так высоко. А это вызовы кода внутри самого контроллера (они ж обычно проецируются от нуля и дальше?), где памяти, как обычно, кот наплакал. И там сидит какой-то инициализирующий код или бутлоадер.

Comment: Собственно, еще и вызываются (по меньшей мере в данном примере) функции THUMB режима (bit 0 адреса установлен) - может, действительно, какие-то подпрограммы ПЗУ?

Comment: Еще вопрос, это код из дампа дизассемблера? Или сгенерированный компилятором? Или написанный человеком?

Comment: Из дампа =) Конкретно кем написан данный вызов - то не ведаю. Либо человеком, либо IAR, но второе - вероятнее - он там ведущий компилятор =D В начале, по адресу 0x44000000 сидит таблица стандартных прерываний для ARM. То есть как бы код там и независимый...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LDR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/Babbfdih.html) имеет различное значение в зависимости от присваиваемых величин.

> The LDR pseudo-instruction is used for two main purposes:
>
> - to generate literal constants when an immediate value cannot be moved into a register because it is out of range of the MOV and MVN instructions.
> - to load a program-relative or external address into a register. The address remains valid regardless of where the linker places the AOF area containing the LDR.

[Список всех команд](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001m/QRC0001_UAL.pdf).

Comment: Значит, это не какая-то хитрость, а корректный адрес, где-то процессору доступный...

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, смотреть на ПСЕВДО-ИНСТРУКЦИЮ LDR Вам НЕ СТОИТ - поскольку Вы явно указали что в данном случае инструкция взята из дампа дизассемблера, не думаю, что дизассемблер так мудр, что сгенерировал для Вас именно псевдо-инструкцию. Скорее всего, в данном случае Вы имеете дело именно с ИНСТРУКЦИЕЙ LDR - Пункты 3.8.2, 4.1.20 в ARM Architecture Reference Manual - единственное, что меня смущает - Loads data FROM THE MEMORY ADDRESS calculated... в то же время, Вы утверждаете, что весь код и данные находятся в другой области памяти... Какие тогда могут быть таблицы адресов в указанной области памяти?

Comment: Не, IDA указатель разыменовывает, если её в настройках об этом попросить, и, так сказать, генерирует псевдо-инструкции, это всё так. Число прям под функцией наблюдается, ида его куда след помещает.

Насколько я уже понял, об этом говорит знак равенства перед вторым операндом - если он есть, это уже разыменованные данные, если нет - это адрес, откуда их брать.

Comment: А не может быть, что дизассемблер ошибочно трактует так какие-то ДАННЫЕ? Откровенно, с ARM не знаком, а с подобным в IBM-360 сталкивался. Ну, еще возможно, это заготовка для самомодифицируемого кода (если это не в ПЗУ, конечно).

Comment: Я нашёл какой-то похожий код от другого телефона, вытянутый через JTAG =) И, судя по всему, он находится в этом диапазоне адресов: от 0x00000000 и выше. Так что, видимо, всё так. Куплю себе отладчик, попробую вытянуть и у себя. Или сделаю...